# Flask/Jinja2 List Item and Conditional Test

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm using Flask/Jinja2, iterating over a list with a for/endfor loop (the list items are lists themselves from a database call), and I need to test the value of one of the items in the inner list.

This test, appearing below, doesn't work (it does nothing).  My guess here is that the Jinja templating system, in a for/endfor loop, doesn't understand list access notation?  Any help?  In the code below, the test `if user[4] == 1` doesn't happen.

```
{% for user in active_users %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ user[1] }}</td>
        <td>{{ user[2] }}</td>
        <td>{{ user[3] }}</td>
        <td>{% if user[4] == 1 %} <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> {% endif %}</td>
        <td><a href="{{ url_for('profile_admin', user_id=user[0]) }}"><i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="{{ url_for('toggle_user_status', user_id=user[0]) }}"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If the loop does nothing then either `active_users` is empty or undefined. Make sure that it is both defined and has elements in it.

Comment: Take your `{%if%}` statement out of the `<td>` tag.  The `if` should come first, then the tag with everything you want when it evaluates to `True`, then the closing tag, then `{%endif%}`.